# Replace the span text in inner div of same name class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a DOM element like

```
<div class="gm-style-cc">
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div><span>some text</span>
    <div>
        <a target="_new">Report a map error</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="gm-style-cc">
    <div>
        <span>5000 km</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to replace km to miles in the second span, but I am not even able to access the particular span

For testing first I tried to change color , 
I have tried the following, but not getting exact values

```
.gm-style-cc:nth-child(1) span {  color: yellow !important; }
.gm-style-cc:nth-child(2) span {  color: green !important; }
.gm-style-cc:nth-child(3) span {  color: green !important; }

----------
span.gm-style-cc:nth-child(1) {  color: yellow !important; }

----------
.gm-style-cc:nth-of-type(1).eq(1) div span{
    color: red !important;
}

-------
.gm-style-cc span{
   color: red !important;
}

-----------
.gm-style-cc:nth-of-type(1).eq(1) div span{
    color: red !important;
}
```

How can I get the specific position of the span element?

Edit : as Mazz suggested

```
.gm-style-cc div span {
    color: red;
}
```

seems to show changes , but it is doing for all span , i want for span in second class

Comment: $(".gm-style-cc div span") ? ... $(".gm-style-cc div span").html("5000 mileswhatever");

Comment: Why don't you set some `id` to your tags? it won't hurt and it'll get easier to select the elements.

Comment: Are you sure that your style samples are getting properly loaded in the code? It looks like your selectors are ok.... I would rather bet on other  more obvious issues

Comment: it is loading from google map api , cant change it

Comment: and what about having googlemap switching to miles adding a country domain to use https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/8T1YPymANfU that's googlemap job, not yours ;)

Comment: i believe thats manual setting we have to do , or another country map we have to load , but that would change language i think . can there be other options as well

Comment: country domain and language can be reset according to your choice of setting .... usually language is picked up from the language the systems runs on ;) try it to check it out ;) (google is actually very invasive tuning the setups for you while collecting datas, how ever it should know the language your browsers uses)

Comment: I am integrating map from api .I am not sure if there is a way to do some setting in that context for imperial unit . i believe your link showing manual setting for the maps

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery you can do the following.

```
$('.gm-style-cc div span').css( 'color', 'red' );
```

Just for the second .gm-style-cc

```
$('.gm-style-cc').eq(1).find('div span').css('color', 'red');
```

This should also work in css

```
.gm-style-cc div span {
    color: red;
}

/* for only the second .gm-style-cc */ 
.gm-style-cc:eq(2) div span {
    color: red;
}
```

You may have to add `!important` if it is from a 3rd party library

To change to content:

```
var sp = $('.gm-style-cc div span');
var value = $('.gm-style-cc div span').text().split(' ');
var newValue = value[0]/1.609344;
sp.text(newValue + ' miles');
```

Comment: How is this at all a relevant answer? "I want to replace km to miles in the second span"

Comment: this seems to show changes in color. but I want for second class span element , how can i correctly do that ? i would also be helpful if you can tell how to replace text with psuedo code

Comment: sp variable showing value but value variable not showing any value

Comment: I also tried  /////////////////
.gm-style-cc:eq(0) div span {
    color: red!important;
}
-----------------
.gm-style-cc:eq(1) div span {
    color: red!important;
}

-------------------
.gm-style-cc:eq(2) div span {
    color: red!important;
} ------------- they are not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use basic JavaScript to find your element and replace `km` with `miles`.

The following code will search for all `span`s that are inside `.gm-style-cc` `div`s and that contain a number followed by `km` in their text, and then do the required replacement:

```js
// Selecting all spans that are inside .gm-style-cc divs
var elms = document.querySelectorAll(".gm-style-cc span");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elms, function(elm) {

  // Check if the text of the element contains a number followed by "km"
  if (elm.innerText.search(/\d+ km/) !== -1) {

    // Converting km to miles
    miles = Number(elm.innerText.split(" ")[0]);
    miles = miles * 0.621371;

    // Creating the new contents
    elm.innerText = String(miles) + " miles";

  }
})
```

```html
<div class="gm-style-cc">
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div><span>some text</span>
  <div>
    <a target="_new">Report a map error</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="gm-style-cc">
  <div>
    <span>5000 km</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 5000 km != 5000 miles

Comment: Edited accordingly

Comment: showing Cannot read property 'innerText' of null error . might be jquery replacement required

Comment: `querySelector` is equivalent to jQuery `$` :)

Comment: still not able to repalce values by that  . console shows no error

Comment: Make sure that you are selecting the right element.

Comment: i am getting value in sp element , but i want to access the second span element . both span element contains text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158520/discussion-between-neeraj-verma-and-ammarx).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one [edited]

```
    (function(){

$('.gm-style-cc').find("span:contains('km')").each(function(i,ele){
        var miles = (parseInt($(this).text(),10) / 1.609344) + ' miles';
        $(ele).text(miles)
 })


})();
```

Comment: nope . $('.gm-style-cc').find("span:contains('km')") showing object array . but inside that it is not going under loop

Comment: ok , you are right , but i m not able to overwrite in google map scale , that my final job to be done , i dont what is wrong with map labels